# Is it necessary to HTTP encode my query parameter when using Python requests.get()

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm using Python's requests library to fetch some data (sample shown below)

```
requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent', headers= headers, params= {'query': 'Python is a good language'}
```

Is it ideal to HTTP encode my 'query' as illustrated below:

```
requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent', headers= headers, params= {'query': 'Python%20is%20a%20good%20language'}
```

I'm not noticing any changes in results if I do not HTTP encode my query. But in the long run will I face any problems/errors? Its very easy to HTTP encode my query using the requests.utils.quote function. I'm better off reliably writing my source code now than revisiting it in the future & having to rethink the code logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look its always good to avoid undefined behavior.
I think the requests library has a function to encode queries.

try something like this:

```
import requests
from requests.utils import quote

query = 'Python is a good language'
encoded_query = quote(query)

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent'
params = {'query': encoded_query}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

This will probably avoid problems in the future.